# Export function return object Object

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import a function from an App.js (it checks the string in the URL) to another module, but outside App.js the function returns an `[object Object]`. Tell me, please, what could be the reason? I tried different syntax for export, the result is the same.

```
export function itTest(){
    const mobileAp = location.search.indexOf("mobile=true") > -1;
    return ( mobileAp
    )}

const test = {itTest};
console.log(test)
[object Ojbect]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're creating an object with a field `itTest` that wraps the function

```
const test = {itTest};
```

if you want to have an alias change it to

```
const test = itTest;
```

or just use `itTest` directly

Comment: oh, thank you very much! But do not tell me why when I call a function, I get the function code, not the result?

Comment: in your sample code, you're not actually calling the function. `itTest` is a reference to the function, you can call it with `itTest()`